# How can I call an action on a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsf, primefaces

How can I call an action on a button click? For example, on click, I want to go to the next page.

```
<s:button id="btn2" action="defineCar.xhtml" ><p:ajax event="click"></p:ajax></s:button>
```

Comment: What about `<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.method}" />`? Redirection on the next page is in outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a backing bean application wide?

Then you could call...

```
<s:button action="#{BeanHandler.goToNextPage}" value="Next" />
```

goToNextPage...

```
public String goToNextPage() {
    //Doing something
    return "NextPage";
}
```

"NextPage" should be in a navigation case in your `faces-config.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), you can bind to the on click event using the following example.

```
$('#btn2').click(function(){
    window.location = 'NextPage.xhtml';
});
```

Make sure this is located in the `$(document).ready()` like below.

```
$(document).ready({
   $('#btn2').click(function(){
     window.location = 'NextPage.xhtml';
   });
});
```

Or, on the button itself, you can simply call the click event directly:

```
<button id="Ok" onclick="window.location='NextPage.xhtml'" class="btn">Ok</button>
```

Comment: thanks Owen .but i want to write custom component width jsf and this way can not help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('button#btn2').click(function(){
// do stuff here
});
```

Comment: thanks sbonkosky . i want to write custom component width jsf and this way can not help me.